# How to check if device supports continuous-picture focus mode?

Tags: android, android-camera, barcode, scanning, vision-api

I'm using the Google Mobile Vision API for my app, everything works as intended, but I ran on a few devices that can't get a barcode to scan. From the logs I found that it's caused by this     `Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE`

I'd gladly like to find a way to get them to work too, but I'd settle with not supporting those devices with my application.

But I just can't find a way to check for this, the only thing I can find is the focus mode.

Thanks!